# char array initialize with string and int variable (c)

Tags: arrays, c, initialization

i would like to initialize a char array like this:

```
char msg[] = "something 12";
```

This works so far, but to hold my function more flexibel i would like to use a integer varible instead of the fixed "12".

So i would like to use something like:

```
int value = 12;
char msg[] = ("something %d", value);
```

But this seems not to work. Is there a smart way use a flexible initialization?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Isn't normal `snprintf()` satisfying you?

Comment: tried at my console, seems to work. thanks, that was the function i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

```
int value = 12;
const char* format = "something %d";
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, format, value);
char msg[len + 1]; /* Variable-Length Array (C99) */
snprintf(msg, len + 1, format, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf` to make up your string:

```
char result[100];
int value = 12;

sprintf(result, "Something %d", value);

printf("%s\n", result);
```